# How Bind database in Checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, checkbox

I want to bind each id from database on SQL Server to a CheckBox. But it doesn't work.

**Here's my code:**

**Table CancelInfo**

```
CancelId | CancelDetail
1 | Cancel01
2 | Cancel02
3 | Cancel03
```

**HTML FROM**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCancel" name="chkCancel" runat="server" OnLoad="chkCancel_Load" />
```

**Code Behind (Class)**

```
public static ClassCancelInfo[] ListCancel()
{
    using (var pcon = new ProjectConnect())
    {
        DataTable table = pcon.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT CancelDetail FROM CancelInfo Where CancelId =1 ");
        CancelInfo[] items = MapFrom(table);
        return items;
    }
}
```

**Code .aspx.cs**

```
protected void chkCancel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkCancel.Text = ClassCancelInfo.ListCancel().ToString();            
}
```

**Result Web Page ,,, □ >> CheckBox**

□ □ □

**But I want Result Web Page**

□ Cancel01

□ Cancel02

□ Cancel03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code as follow:

```
<% 
 int i=0;
foreach (ClassCancelInfo ci in ClassCancelInfo.ListCancel())
{ 
%>

<input type='checkbox' id="chk_<%=i.ToString()%>"/>
<label for="chk_<%=i.ToString()%>"><%=ci.CancelDetail%></label>
<br/>
<% i=i+1;
 } 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using `inline syntax with foreach` loop

```
  <% foreach(ClassCancelInfo ci in ClassCancelInfo.ListCancel()){  %>

         <asp:CheckBox ID="chk__<%= counter++ %>" value= "<%= ci.Value%>" /> 
         <%= ci.CancelDetail%>

         </br>
  <%  } %>
```

Comment: i try this code. don't' work because Text Checkbox don't show.

Comment: @nettoon493, I think you are using `CancelDetail` property of CancelInfo class for display. I updated my answer.